# Can an Illusion wizard make invisibility "real"?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, illusion

If a level 20 Wizard (School of Illusion) casts Invisibility on a creature and then uses its 14th level ability *illusory reality* to make the invisibility "real", what happens?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### No.

[Illusory Reality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion) says (PHB, pg. 118):

> you can **choose one inanimate, nonmagical object** that is part of the illusion and make that object real.

A creature is not inanimate, and invisibility is not an object.

Comment: You may want to address what, if anything, happens if you target an object that the creature affected by *invisibility* is carrying since "Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person."

Comment: I’d probably rule that Invisibility doesn’t create an illusion, so nothing made invisible is a valid target for Illusory Reality - the object already is real, just invisible, and as I stated in the answer, invisibility is not an object at all, illusory or otherwise.